# AI Platform Notebook Always Python 2

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am trying to create a Python 3 Notebook in GCP AI Platform Notebooks but the kernel is always python 2.

After creating a new "Python 3" notebook, the kernel in the top right correctly shows python 3 but `! python --version` returns `Python 2.7.13` and

```
x = 1
f"{x}"
```

throws a SyntaxError. Selecting Python 3 in the top right, restarting the kernel, and restarting the instance does not change the result.

I can see that python 3 is installed from terminal, `$ python3 --version` -> `Python 3.5.3` so the launcher appears to be busted!

I then SSH'ed onto the instance, and ran jupyter notebook (which correctly points to python 3.5)

```
zre@intel-20200218:~$ jupyter notebook
[I 17:55:35.993 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jupyterlab
[I 17:55:35.993 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[I 17:55:36.453 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/zre
```

But still hit this behavior:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp9NA.png)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of different python version present in system

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
```

when you do this you will be seeing a output like this
    /usr/bin/python  /usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python2.7  /usr/bin/python3
    /usr/bin/python3.5  /usr/bin/python3.5m  /usr/bin/python3m

Open ~/.bashrc file and add new alias to change your default python executable

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.5'
. ~/.bashrc
```

Now check your python version

```
python --version
```

Comment: Mark this as answer, if it answers your question

Comment: Good idea! I went ahead and added the alias to my .bashrc and sourced it. Now, in terminal  `python --version` does infact return `Python 3.5.3` but creating a new Python 3 Jupter Notebook continues to use Python 2 even though the kernel pull down is set to Python 3! I even restarted the instance to no avail.

Comment: you can run on virtual environmement that handles diffrent version for your projects

Comment: Follow this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-jupyter-notebook-for-python-3

Comment: I was able to SSH onto the instance, activate my virtual environment (targeting python 3) and start a notebook, but it does not create a public URL `No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.` Is [this the documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#notebook-public-server) I need to follow?